# Punctuation of abbreviation followed by parenthesis

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations

Best just to give you the example, rather than explain it. This has been a hard one to solve - harder than I thought it would be.

Created by XYZ Ltd. (best company in the world).

Is this correct? There are two closing periods here, but it doesn't look right to drop the second one. The first one is part of the company name and required.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, a full stop (period) is not used where an abbreviation starts and ends with the same letters as the word it abbreviates.

This is supported by the Oxford Dictionary's [Punctuation in abbreviations](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/punctuation-in-abbreviations).

So for example in BrE

- Mister is abbreviated to **Mr**
- Etcetera is abbreviated to **etc.**
- Limited is abbreviated to **Ltd**

The description "limited" often applies to a British companies, although some American ones are Ltd. rather than LLC.

So in AmE it would be correct to write

> Created by XYZ Ltd. (best company in the world).

whereas in BrE it would be

> Created by XYZ Ltd (best company in the world).